# Crawling google search url list with python

Tags: python, web, web-crawler

I'd like to scrape google search result url with python.

Here's my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def search(keyword):        
    html = requests.get('https://www.google.co.kr/search?q={}&num=100&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8'.format(keyword)).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    result = []
    for i in soup.find_all('h3', {'class':'r'}):
        result.append(i.find('a', href = True) ['href'][7:])
    return result

search('computer')
```

Then I can get result. First url of the list is wikipedia.com which is,

'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwixyfu7q5HdAhWR3lQKHUfoDcsQFggTMAA&usg=AOvVaw2nvT-2sO4iJenW_fkyCS3i',
 '?q=computer&num=100&ie=UTF-8&prmd=ivnsbp&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixyfu7q5HdAhWR3lQKHUfoDcsQsAQIHg'

I want to get clean url, which is 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer' including all the other search result in this case.

How can I modify my codes?

**Edited**: As you see the image below, I want to get the real url (marked yellow), not the messy and long url above.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about appending

```
.split('&')[0]
```

to your code, in a way such that it becomes:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def search(keyword):
    html = requests.get('https://www.google.co.kr/search?q={}&num=100&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8'.format(keyword)).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    result = []
    for i in soup.find_all('h3', {'class':'r'}):
        result.append(i.find('a', href = True) ['href'][7:].split('&')[0])
    return result

search('computer')
```

[EDIT]

Taking `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer` as an example:

Through chrome developer tools the url looks clean.

Since it belongs to `<h3 class="r">`, your code should work fine and return the clean url.

Instead, if you replace

```
result.append(i.find('a', href = True) ['href'][7:])
```

with

```
print i
```

then in my terminal it returns the following for the above link:

```
/url?q=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwinqcqdypHdAhVhKH0KHVWIBEUQFggfMAU&amp;usg=AOvVaw1pduIWw_TSCJUxtP9W_kHJ
```

you can see that `/url?q=` has been prepended, and `&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwinqcqdypHdAhVhKH0KHVWIBEUQFggfMAU&amp;usg=AOvVaw1pduIWw_TSCJUxtP9W_kHJ`
 has been appended.

By looking at other links as well, I observed that the prepended part always looks like `/url?q=`, and the appended part always begins with a `&`.

Therefore it's my belief that my original answer should work:

```
result.append(i.find('a', href = True) ['href'][7:].split('&')[0])
```

`[7:]` removes the prepended string, and `split('&')[0]` the appended string.

Comment: That's only viable for one link that he gave up there. It'll crash if theres a link that doesn't contain an ampersand.

Comment: @JosephSeungJaeDollar  Right, I need universal method applied to every url collected.

Comment: @JosephSeungJaeDollar I'm pretty sure it won't crash, the link will remain as it is if it doesn't contain an ampersand.

Comment: @WookeunLee + links are usually made 'unclean' by `&` and `?` , so you could just continue adding corresponding conditions ( `.split('?')[0]` for example) till you get the result you want.

My results look fine with the ampersand split alone though.

Comment: @ wookiekim I modified my question, check it out again.

Comment: @WookeunLee edited my answer, although the code remains the same.
I still believe it should work, but you can choose not to use it anyway.
++some irrelevant links may get mixed into the results, but you can filter them out later.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution.

This modification in the search function works.

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36'}     
    html = requests.get('https://www.google.co.kr/search?q={}&num=100&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8'.format(keyword), headers = headers).text
```